# Java: Is there a way to get the expected uncompressed length of a zipped byte array?

Tags: java, zip

I'm using `java.util.zip` to compress and uncompress byte arrays, using `Inflater` and `Deflater`.

Does the compressed result contain information about the expected length of the original data or do I have to store it myself?

I would like to know the expected length of the uncompressed information without uncompressing all of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just compress and decompress byte arrays - without storing them in a `ZipEntry` - you must save the size yourself, as the byte array to which you compress the data is not necessarily used to its full extent.

You can see this clearly from the example in `Deflater`'s [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html):

```
try {
     // Encode a String into bytes
     String inputString = "blahblahblah??";
     byte[] input = inputString.getBytes("UTF-8");

     // Compress the bytes
     byte[] output = new byte[100];
     Deflater compresser = new Deflater();
     compresser.setInput(input);
     compresser.finish();
     int compressedDataLength = compresser.deflate(output);

     // Decompress the bytes
     Inflater decompresser = new Inflater();
     decompresser.setInput(output, 0, compressedDataLength);
     byte[] result = new byte[100];
     int resultLength = decompresser.inflate(result);
     decompresser.end();

     // Decode the bytes into a String
     String outputString = new String(result, 0, resultLength, "UTF-8");
 } catch(java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
     // handle
 } catch (java.util.zip.DataFormatException ex) {
     // handle
 }
```

The code must maintain the compressed data's lenght as the output array is of length 100, no matter the actual length of the data it stores.